# Migrating from joomla 1.5 to 2.5 along with VirtueMart 1.9 to the supported version with 2.5

Tags: joomla-2.5, migration, joomla-1.5, virtuemart

I've have a site built in with **`Joomla 1.5`** having `VirtueMart 1.9`. Now I've to make the copy of that site with few more plugins to install and they are not available in 1.5 version so **I have to upgrade to Joomla 2.5 with the supported version of VirtueMart.**

As my site have many extensions but most important of them is VirtueMart.

I've tried redMIGRATOR which copies the database but what about my design and other plugins?

What should I do to make the new copy of site as same as previous with the updated versions of Joomla and VirtueMart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrating Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 might be a complex process, depending on what extensions you have on your current website. It's almost never a one-click process. The same goes for Virtuemart. VirtueMart 2.x.x is a completely new shopping cart system which is not compatible with VirtueMart 1, and a one-click upgrade does not exist.

First of all, **make sure you have a complete backup of your site** (I recommend [Akeeba Backup](http://www.akeebabackup.com))

There are many ways to do the migration, I'm going to list a couple of alternatives, but first keep in mind the following:

1. Your current template will most probably not work with Joomla 2.5. You'll have to:

   - modify it to make it compatible
   - download a new version from the template provider (if available)
   - use a different template
2. You'll have to look for an upgraded version of most of your extensions.
3. Virtuemart 2 does not use templates like VM1 did, any layout overrides comes from your Joomla template.

#### 1. Build a new site

Taking into account the points above, you might be better of creating a completely new site. Then use [J2XML](http://www.eshiol.it/) to import articles (with images), categories, menus and users. This will give you a kickstart, and the advantage is that you have a very clean J2.5 installation.

Then install Virtuemart 2, and set up your products again. If you have few products, I think this is the easiest way.

#### 2. Use Virtuemart 2 Migrator

<sup>DISCLAIMER: I haven't tried this component myself</sup>

[Virtuemart 2 Migrator](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-administration/25279) is a commercial extension that claims it can migrate both Joomla and Virtuemart.

> This migrator, is a giant leap towards Joomla 2.5 and VirtueMart 2 !
>   Every VirtueMart content from your shop will be copied over. Here is
>   how it works.
>
> - Install blank Joomla 2.5 and VirtueMart 2 on the same server as your existing website
> - Install VirtueMart 2 Migrator component and configure database access and file paths
> - Select the contents you want to migrate and hit the "Migrate now button"

#### Try other migration tools

A list of different tools for Joomla migration is available at [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration). As long as you work on a copy of your site, there's nothing wrong with testing different solutions (except it might be time consuming).

#### Other information

- A guide called [Complete Guide for Joomla 1.5.26-2.5.X & VM1.X TO VM2.X MIGRATION](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=102783.0) is available at the Virtuemart forum, it might be worth a look.
- VirtueMart 3 (compatible with Joomla 3) is just around the corner. Actually, VM2.9.9B (Release Candidate) is available for [download](http://virtuemart.net/download). You might want to consider going directly to Joomla 3/VirtueMart 3.

Comment: I have done many complex migrations such as the above. Looking at the number of products in the VM cart or the sheer number of content items, it SEEMS like migration is the best idea.

In actuality, you will spend less time and have fewer headaches starting with a fresh site.  You'll need a new template anyway.  I further agree with johanpw that you should try to start with J 3.X from the get-go.  There are so many reasons! I've migrated nearly all my clients from 2.x to 3.x and the difference is night and day.

Comment: Awesome @johanpw for your suggestions and thorough answer.Thumbs up