# Migrating Site from 2.5 to 3.4

Tags: joomla-2.5, joomla-3.4, virtuemart

I want to update my [Joomla site](http://www.bioproduction.dk/testversion/index.php?lang=da) from 2.5 to 3.x.

First I updated all the extensions whith available updates, then I ran the Joomla update. After updating site I got the following errors:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/bioproduct/domains/bioproduction.dk/public_html/testversion/plugins/system/truetypography/truetypography.php on line 50
>
> Warning: require(/home/bioproduct/domains/bioproduction.dk/public_html/testversion/libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bioproduct/domains/bioproduction.dk/public_html/testversion/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/vmmodel.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/bioproduct/domains/bioproduction.dk/public_html/testversion/libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/bioproduct/domains/bioproduction.dk/public_html/testversion/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/vmmodel.php on line 24

In configuration the `public $error_reporting = 'maximum';`

Comment: On a production sites, error reporting should be set to `default`. Please change this in your configuration.php

Comment: sir i change it to default

Comment: Do you have access to your **php.ini** file?

Comment: sir in which directory it is ?

Comment: It's not part of Joomla. It's a server file.

Comment: what kind of change it needs ...

Comment: You'll need to disable strict errors. These types of errors aren't really a big issue. Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9984309/1362108

Comment: but sir its not showing its front end and back end as well..

Comment: The answer link I provided you with will work for both the front-end and back-end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31502/discussion-between-shehryar-and-lodder).

Comment: In addition to these comments, error reporting should be NONE on a production site. System default have very different results depending on the systems configuration. Further more, this wouldn't solve your problem in anyway but just hide the obvious fatal error message. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that virtuemart is out of date and therefore causing the issues as per the last part of your fatal error message.

You need to disable all virtuemart plugins prior to the update to Joomla! 3.x then once updated you download and install Virtuemart 3 and follow their update instructions also.

If you have already upgrade to Joomla! 3.x then disable the virtuemart system plugin in the Joomla! Extensions table of the database with the likes of phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading a site using Virtuemart is almost never a one-click upgrade. I wrote a post some time ago on [Joomla/Virtuemart upgrades](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/migrating-from-joomla-1-5-to-2-5-along-with-virtuemart-1-9-to-the-supported-vers/4624#4624), although for previous versions.

Try upgrading to Virtuemart 3 first (if you haven't done it already). Virtuemart 2.x does not work in Joomla 3 ([as mentioned here](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=127714.0)). The [upgrade](http://docs.virtuemart.net/tutorials/installation-migration-upgrade/198-upgrade-virtuemart-2-to-virtuemart-3.html) should be quite straight forward, but there's no guarantee it will work right out of the box.

I often find it quicker (and easier) to start a new store from scratch, and create products and categories again. It might sound like unnecessary work, but compared to all the trouble-shooting you have to do after a one-click upgrade, it might actually be quicker. You'll get a clean start, and you can (manually) copy most of the settings from your previous store, thus saving you some time.

In addition, you're getting a less important `strict standards` error with a plugin called [True Typography](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/true-typography), you should upgrade or disable this plugin.